# React - How to render nested component instead of [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a quiz with a few questions/answers using an `Accordion`, `AccordionItem`, and `Link`.
Everything works great except for the `Link`, it renders perfectly when outside the accordion component line 50 in the fiddle, but does not work when it is nested in `sampleQuestions > question1 > answer`, line 59 in the fiddle.

It renders the answer as:
`Ottawa baby!! Check [object Object] for more details.`

Instead of the desired link: `Ottawa baby!! Check wikipedia link b for more details.`

Here is the code for reference, but I recommend skipping directly to the fiddle below the code, clicking the first question, and seeing the issue first hand.

```
class Link extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <span onClick={this.props.onClick} className="link">{this.props.linkTitle}</span>
    );
  }
}

class AccordionItem extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      active: false
    };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      active: !this.state.active,
      className: "active"
    });
  }
  render() {
    const activeClass = this.state.active ? "active" : "inactive";
    const question = this.props.details;
    return (
            <div className={activeClass} onClick={this.toggle}>
              <span className="summary">{question.summary}</span>
              <span className="folding-pannel answer">{question.answer}</span>
            </div>
    );
  }
}

class Accordion extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      questions: sampleQuestions,
    };
    this.renderQuestion = this.renderQuestion.bind(this);
  }
  renderQuestion(key) {
    return <AccordionItem key={key} index={key} details={this.state.questions[key]} />
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="mainbody">
        <h1>What is...</h1>
        <Link onClick={() => alert('outside link works')} linkTitle={'wikipedia link a'} />
        <div className="accordion-container">
          {Object.keys(this.state.questions).map(this.renderQuestion)}
        </div>
      </div>    
    )
  }
}
const sampleQuestions = {
  question1: {summary:'the capital of Canada?', answer:'Ottawa baby!! Check ' + <Link onClick={() => alert('trying to get this nested link to show')} linkTitle={'wikipedia link b'} /> + ' for more details.'},
  question2: {summary:'the life span of a bowhead whale?', answer:'Over 200 years!!'},
  question3: {summary:'the most visited city in the world?', answer:'London, groovy baby!!'},
  question4: {summary:'the warmest ocean?', answer:'Indian Ocean, it\'s a hottie!'},
  question5: {summary:'the one thing ron swanson hates more than lying?', answer:'Skim milk, which is water that\'s lying about being milk'}
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Accordion />,
  document.getElementById('accordion')
);
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLeZVQ)

Any idea how to get the `[object Object]` to render the desired `Link` component for the first question's answer?

Comment: Rather than have answer be a string change it to JSX. wrap it in a div and have the text in the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all those who answered, but I found a much less obtrusive way of doing it. As patrick suggested in the comments, simply turning the answer to a jsx instead of a string by wrapping it in a div works perfectly.

This is what it looks like now:

```
answer: <div>Ottawa baby!! Check <Link onClick={() => alert('trying to get this nested link to show')} linkTitle={'wikipedia link b'} /> for more details.</div>
```

This is the simplest solution and gets the link to render as expected.

Comment: You won't need to use `div`s if you replace it with React's `<Fragment>`. Same concept, cleaner DOM. See first example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Here's one way of doing it: Utilizing React Fragment.

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/92r12m7zp

**public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect fill="rgba(159, 188, 191, 0.15)" x="0" width="20" height="20" y="0" />
            <rect fill="rgba(159, 188, 191, 0.15)" x="20" width="20" height="20" y="20" />
        </pattern>
        <rect fill="url(#pattern)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </svg>
    <div id="accordion"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Accordian from "./Accordian";
import "./styles.css";

render(<Accordian />, document.getElementById("accordion"));
```

**Accordian.js**

```
import map from "lodash/map";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AccordionItem from "./AccordianItem";
import SampleQuestions from "./sampleQuestions";

export default class Accordion extends Component {
  state = { questions: SampleQuestions };

  render = () => (
    <div className="mainbody">
      <h1>What is...</h1>
      <div className="accordion-container">
        {map(this.state.questions, ({ key, ...rest }) => (
          <AccordionItem key={key} {...rest} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**AccordianItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class AccordionItem extends Component {
  state = { isActive: false };

  toggle = () => this.setState(prevState => ({ isActive: !this.state.isActive }));

  render = () => (
    <div
      className={`${this.state.isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}`}
      onClick={this.toggle}
    >
      <span className="summary">&#62; {this.props.summary}</span>
      <span className="folding-pannel answer">
        {this.props.answer}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**sampleQuestions.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

const Link = url => (
  <a href={url} target="_blank">
    here
  </a>
);

export default [
  {
    key: "capital-of-canada",
    summary: "the capital of Canada?",
    answer: (
      <Fragment>
        Ottawa baby!! Click {Link("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottawa")} for
        more details
      </Fragment>
    )
  },
  {
    key: "whale-lifespan",
    summary: "the life span of a bowhead whale?",
    answer: "Over 200 years!!"
  },
  {
    key: "most-popular-city",
    summary: "the most visited city in the world?",
    answer: "London, groovy baby!!"
  },
  {
    key: "warmest-ocean",
    summary: "the warmest ocean?",
    answer: "Indian Ocean, it's a hottie!"
  },
  {
    key: "swanson",
    summary: "the one thing ron swanson hates more than lying?",
    answer: "Skim milk, which is water that's lying about being milk"
  }
];
```

---

### Here's another way of doing it: Utilizing arrays with mixed content.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/1v1xmq1kmq

**public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect fill="rgba(159, 188, 191, 0.15)" x="0" width="20" height="20" y="0" />
            <rect fill="rgba(159, 188, 191, 0.15)" x="20" width="20" height="20" y="20" />
        </pattern>
        <rect fill="url(#pattern)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </svg>
    <div id="accordion"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Accordian from "./Accordian";
import "./styles.css";

render(<Accordian />, document.getElementById("accordion"));
```

**Accordian.js**

```
import map from "lodash/map";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AccordionItem from "./AccordianItem";
import SampleQuestions from "./sampleQuestions";

export default class Accordion extends Component {
  state = { questions: SampleQuestions };

  render = () => (
    <div className="mainbody">
      <h1>What is...</h1>
      <div className="accordion-container">
        {map(this.state.questions, ({ key, ...rest }) => (
          <AccordionItem key={key} {...rest} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**AccordianItem.js**

```
import each from "lodash/each";
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import uuid from "uuid/v5";

export default class AccordionItem extends Component {
  state = { isActive: false };

  toggle = () => this.setState(prevState => ({ isActive: !this.state.isActive }));

  render = () => (
    <div
      className={`${this.state.isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}`}
      onClick={this.toggle}
    >
      <span className="summary">&#62; {this.props.summary}</span>
      <span className="folding-pannel answer">
        {each(this.props.answer, prop => <Fragment key={uuid}>{prop}</Fragment>)}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**sampleQuestions.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Link = url => (
  <a href={url} target="_blank">
    here
  </a>
);

export default [
  {
    key: "capital-of-canada",
    summary: "the capital of Canada?",
    answer: [
      "Ottawa baby!! Click ",
      Link("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottawa"),
      " for more details"
    ]
  },
  {
    key: "whale-lifespan",
    summary: "the life span of a bowhead whale?",
    answer: ["Over 200 years!!"]
  },
  {
    key: "most-popular-city",
    summary: "the most visited city in the world?",
    answer: ["London, groovy baby!!"]
  },
  {
    key: "warmest-ocean",
    summary: "the warmest ocean?",
    answer: ["Indian Ocean, it's a hottie!"]
  },
  {
    key: "swanson",
    summary: "the one thing ron swanson hates more than lying?",
    answer: ["Skim milk, which is water that's lying about being milk"]
  }
];
```

---

### Here's yet another way of doing it: Utilizing [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) with [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html).

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/0q1mv0omkw

**public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect fill="rgba(159, 188, 191, 0.15)" x="0" width="20" height="20" y="0" />
            <rect fill="rgba(159, 188, 191, 0.15)" x="20" width="20" height="20" y="20" />
        </pattern>
        <rect fill="url(#pattern)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </svg>
    <div id="accordion"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Accordian from "./Accordian";
import "./styles.css";

render(<Accordian />, document.getElementById("accordion"));
```

**Accordian.js**

```
import map from "lodash/map";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AccordionItem from "./AccordianItem";
import SampleQuestions from "./sampleQuestions";

export default class Accordion extends Component {
  state = { questions: SampleQuestions };

  render = () => (
    <div className="mainbody">
      <h1>What is...</h1>
      <div className="accordion-container">
        {map(this.state.questions, ({ key, ...rest }) => (
          <AccordionItem key={key} {...rest} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**AccordianItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import sanitizeHtml from "sanitize-html";

export default class AccordionItem extends Component {
  state = { isActive: false };

  toggle = () => this.setState(prevState => ({ isActive: !this.state.isActive }));

  sanitize = ans =>
    sanitizeHtml(ans, {
      allowedTags: ["a"],
      allowedAttributes: {
        a: ["href", "target"]
      }
    });

  render = () => (
    <div
      className={`${this.state.isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}`}
      onClick={this.toggle}
    >
      <span className="summary">&#62; {this.props.summary}</span>
      <span
        className="folding-pannel answer"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: this.sanitize(this.props.answer)
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**sampleQuestions.js**

```
const Link = url => `<a href=${url} target="_blank">here</a>`;

export default [
  {
    key: "capital-of-canada",
    summary: "the capital of Canada?",
    answer: `Ottawa baby!! Click ${Link("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottawa")} for more details`
  },
  {
    key: "whale-lifespan",
    summary: "the life span of a bowhead whale?",
    answer: "Over 200 years!!"
  },
  {
    key: "most-popular-city",
    summary: "the most visited city in the world?",
    answer: "London, groovy baby!!"
  },
  {
    key: "warmest-ocean",
    summary: "the warmest ocean?",
    answer: "Indian Ocean, it's a hottie!"
  },
  {
    key: "swanson",
    summary: "the one thing ron swanson hates more than lying?",
    answer: "Skim milk, which is water that's lying about being milk"
  }
];
```

Comment: This approach seems like it's going down the wrong path. A better solution would be to intervene earlier to have it render the right thing.

Comment: Updated answer to include 3 different ways to handle strings with some html elements.

Comment: Thanks but I found a much cleaner solution and posted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really put a react component inside of a string generally. There are ways to do it, namely by using `react-jsx-parser`, but we won't go into that.

One possibly solution is doing the following: Setting up a dumb component that renders an array of children.

```
const AnswerWithLink = (children) => {
  return (
    <span>{[...children]}</span>
  )
}
```

And then on answer 1, you call that as a function and pass the parts of the string as elements of the array:

```
question1: {
  summary:'the capital of Canada?', 
  answer: AnswerWithLink(['Ottawa baby!! Check ', Link({onClick: () => alert('trying to get this nested link to show'), linkTitle: 'wikipedia link b'}), ' for more details'])
}
```

I'm sure there are more efficient ways of doing this though.

Edit: I've also edited the codepen to make it work. Also ended up changing `<Link />` to be a dumb component, as it is stateless.

Comment: Thanks but I found a much cleaner solution and posted it.